# How to remove a new line from an NSArray output

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm trying to remove the new line return from an NSArray output. I first converted it to a NSString to remove the () but the new line still shows up

```
NSString *myArrayString = [self.selectedStates description];

NSCharacterSet *charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()\n\""];
myArrayString = [myArrayString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
```

the output I have looks like the following. I need to remove the new lines from somehow, so instead of this:

```
   1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6
```

I would have `1,2,4,5,6`

Comment: Why don't you try , \\n instead of \n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relying on `description` is *not a good idea*. How about doing it **the right way?**

```
NSString *desc = [theArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

(You can do it the way you approached it, by the way:

```
NSString *desc = [[theArray description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

but again, don't do this, please.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByString:(NSString *)separator` method of `NSArray`

E.g.

```
NSArray *pathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"here", @"be", @"dragons", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",[pathArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
```